# iOS запись стерео звука

Tags: ios, iphone

Ищу способ записи звука на iPhone со всех микрофонов одновременно или хотя бы с двух для записи стерео. Просмотрел несколько тем на англоязычной версии этого ресурса, но все темы созданы до 2017 года, и в них говорится об отсутствии возможности такой записи по причине одноканального входящего аудио-потока.

Дальнейшие поиски натолкнули на информацию о том, что iPhone XS может писать видео со стерео звуком.

Уважаемые коллеги, будьте любезны, подскажите, как решить данную проблему или хотя бы где искать.